# main=paste( substitute(...), substitute(...) ) in R_hist_title

Tags: r, title

I'm trying to assemble a title for a histogram plot in R. The title I want derives from two sources, first a vector (death.cause) specifying, er, cause-of-death, and second a field from a data.frame, into which I index using a list, deathratecols, to get at the field.

```
> death.cause 

> [[1]] [1] "Heart Attack"
> 
> [[2]] [1] "Heart Failure"
> 
> [[3]] [1] "Pneumonia"


> deathratecols

> [1] 11 17 23
```

I want to assemble title like: Heart Attack (x-bar = 7.63763) , where x-bar is the mean of the data column. I can get the two parts to work separately as below.

```
> main=substitute(x, list(x=death.cause[[i]]) )) # gives title "Heart Attack" 

> main=substitute(bar(X)==k, list(k=mean(outcome[, deathratecols[i] ], na.rm=TRUE   ) )) # gives title x-bar=7.63763
```

But my efforts to put the two together using paste() have failed.

? someone point out the error of my ways please

Answer (score 2):

Format the title ahead of time with a `sprintf` statement and pass it to `main`. Trivial example:

```
a <- "foo"
b <- "bar"
title <- sprintf("This combines %s and %s", a, b)
hist(rnorm(10), main = title)
```

Perhaps something like this (but might not work since you didn't provide an example to work with):

```
title <- sprintf("%s, (x-bar = %s)", death.cause[[i]], mean(outcome[, deathratecols[i]])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, which gave me a stimulus to learn about yet another part of R. I was not able to make sprintf() work as I needed. However for the record I found that substitute() can be used to assemble a string in much the same way as paste(), albeit without needing comma's between the args, so the    `code main=substitute( cod ( bar(x)==y ), list(cod=death.cause[[i]], y=round(mean(outcome[, deathratecols[i] ], na.rm=TRUE   ), 2  )`

Comment: ... gave me the title I wanted i.e. CauseOfDeath(xbar=RateColumnMean) Thanks again for your suggestion. B

Answer (score 0):

You can combine substitute() and paste() like below:

```
hist(outcome[, deathratecols[i]], 
     main=substitute(paste(death.cause[[i]], "(", bar(X), "=", k, ")"), list(k=mean(outcome[, deathratecols[i]], na.rm=TRUE))))
```

It worked for me.